# "Folder not found" message on login

Tags: kde

Every time I log in, a strange message appears saying that a folder in my home directory I created for a project "does not exist".

I don't recall putting any widgets on my desktop that use the folder. The DE is KDE, and I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

How can I prevent the message from appearing whenever I log in, other than creating the folder?

[image]

Comment: check ~/.config/autostart and $KDEHOME/Autostart and comment any non required line

Comment: `~/.config/autostart` is a folder with three files in it, none of which have any line with the project folder in it :s

Comment: What about $KDEHOME/Autostart and ~/.profile and /etc/profile ?

Comment: Doesn't look like `$KDEHOME/autostart` exists... the other two are scripts that do not mention the project folder

Comment: A is capital in $KDEHOME/Autostart

Comment: `ls $KDEHOME/Autostart` returns `No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21800/discussion-between-ubuntu99-and-richard).

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a Plasma widget was set to use this folder.

Check if you have any widgets (e.g. FolderView widget) using this directory.

Comment: That's what I suspected, at first - the only thing that really has anything to do with folders is a Shelf that I had, and I tried removing it and logging out and in again. No luck ):

Comment: Try exploring `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`, maybe you can find the cause there. Or move the file somewhere else (to be able to restore it if needed) and re-log-in.